# Coin with claim#1: fair, claim#2: P(head)=0.6, refute at least one with 99% chance

Tags: probability

I've encountered the following problem, and would like to receive some help:

We have a coin. $A$ claims it's a $fair$ one, $B$ claims it has a $60\%$ probability of getting a $head$.
What is the minimum number of trials that should refute at least one of the claims with $99\%$ chance?

Let $P(head)=p$ to simplify things.
I calculated the expected values and variances for both cases but my main problem is that we don't even know whether $p \in \{0.5;0.6\}$  is true or not. Anyway, I tried using Chebyshev's inequality but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: More information is needed to determine the probability that the coin is fair. Does the coin look easy to tamper with? Who has previously handled it?

Comment: Where is this problem from? I think we need to decide on a prior probability distribution on $p$.

Comment: I heard it from a friend. Tbh I think the information provided should be enough. The worst case intuitively is $p=0.55$, that case takes the most trials to refute a claim. Still don't know what to do :/

Comment: If you want to refute either of these hypotheses you must specify with which confidence you want to refute. Do you really want to determine $n$ such that the probability that a coin with arbitrary true head probability $p$ will produce a result that will very likely (99%) refute at least one of the two hypotheses at the selected (but hitherto unspecified) significance level? Or you you want to find $n$ such that for arbitrary $p$ th eresult of $n$ trials will *definitely* refute at least one of th etwo hypotheses at a 99% significance level?

Comment: The latter. Minimum $n$ number of trials definitely refuting at least one hypothesis at a 0.99 significance level.

Comment: @user88954: What according to you does it mean to refute? Suppose you toss the coin 10 times and see all heads. What do you conclude from this? Does it refute either of the claims, according to you? How, and with what number/chance/probability/significance (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

You need various assumptions including a normal approximation, but if you assume for simplicity that the standard deviation of the sample mean is $1/\sqrt{4n}$ (it may be less than that, so this is slightly conservative) and that you want the distance between $0.5$ and $0.6$ to be at least twice $2.576$ standard deviations (since $\Phi(2.576) \approx 0.995002$, which is what you want if you are using a two-sided test to reject) then you need to solve $$2 \times 2.576 \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n}} \ge 0.6-0.5$$ which will give you $n \ge (25.76)^2 \approx 664$.

You could get a slightly lower figure if the individuals were confident about their claims. Suppose you took a sample size of $537$ and said that A is the winner if $295$ or fewer heads occurred and B was the winner if $296$ heads or more occurred. Then [using an exact binomial distribution]  A would expect to win with probability over $0.9901$ and B would expect to win with probability over $0.9903$, which they may both see as good enough.  Something similar is not possible with a sample size of $548$, but is possible with a sample size of $549$ or more.  This is analogous to using one-sided confidence intervals.

Comment: Could you explain the basic idea of what's going on here? How do refute a claim like this in the first place? Suppose you toss the coin 10 (or 100, or 1000) times and see it to be all heads (or all heads but one, and one tail, if "all heads" is an extreme case that causes any difficulty). What can you conclude from this / how do you refute the claim that $p = 0.5$, for instance? (Basically, with 100 coin flips, say, I know how to calculate $P(100\text{ heads}|p=0.5)$, but I‌ don't know how to get to something like $P(p=0.5|100\text{ heads})$ without assuming a prior distribution on $p$.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: In my first example, if you toss the coin $1000$ times and it is heads every time, then the probability of seeing a result as extreme as this or more if the probability of a head is $0.5$ is  $2/2^{1000} \lt 0.01$, so you can reject this at the 99% level.  This is standard frequentist [hypothesis testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing).  Indeed if you get more than $541$ heads or fewer then $459$ heads, you can reject the $0.5$ hypothesis at the 99% level.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand correctly, if P(results|A)<1%, you refute/reject A at "99% level". This means that if A were true, there's a less than 1% chance this would happen. This is different from saying that we're 99% confident that A is false (which we cannot say here). Correct?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR In my first example, it is $\Pr(\text{results or more extreme}|A) \lt 0.01$ and the "more extreme" is important. This is how you reject (not refute) a statistical hypothesis: you are very unlikely to have seen anything as extreme as the results if the hypothesis were true. But $A$ is very probably false anyway without doing an experiment since a coin you think has a probability of $0.5$ of being heads might almost equally well have a probability of $0.500000000000000000001$ because of its atomic structure or any number in between and you have no way of telling.

Comment: Thanks. I used "refute" because that was what the OP wanted. :) I'm still uncomfortable with the fact that our conclusion seems backwards (we're concluding the hypothesis is false because if it were true the results would be unlikely, rather than concluding from the results that the _hypothesis_ is unlikely). But I guess this is the so-called Bayesian-versus-frequentist controversy, about which I've heard a lot but never really understood.